# How do I paste the copied text from keyboard in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, pyperclip

If I execute this code, it works fine. But if I copy something using the keyboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), then how can I paste the text present on clipboard in any entry box or text box in python?

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
spam = pyperclip.paste()
```

Answer (score 3):

You will want to pass `pyperclip.paste()` the same place you would place a string for your entry or text widget inserts.

Take a look at this example code.

There is a button to copy what is in the entry field and one to paste to entry field.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pyperclip

root = tk.Tk()

some_entry = tk.Entry(root)
some_entry.pack()

def update_btn():
    global some_entry
    pyperclip.copy(some_entry.get())

def update_btn_2():
    global some_entry
    # for the insert method the 2nd argument is always the string to be
    # inserted to the Entry field.
    some_entry.insert(tk.END, pyperclip.paste())

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Copy to clipboard", command = update_btn)
btn.pack()

btn2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Paste current clipboard", command = update_btn_2)
btn2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively you could just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the following line, because it overwrites what you have copied with the keyboard.

```
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
```

---

For example, I copied you question's title, and here's how I pasted it into python shell:

```
>>> import pyperclip 
>>> pyperclip.paste() 
'How do I paste the copied text from keyboard in python\n\n'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using `tkinter` in your code, and all you need is the content in the clipboard. Then `tkinter` has an in-built method to do just that.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
spam = root.clipboard_get()
```

To add the copied text in a `tkinter` Entry/Textbox, you can use a `tkinter` variable:

```
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set(spam)
```

And link that variable to the Entry widget.

```
box = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = var)
```