# Paste from clipboard to excel file

Tags: python, clipboard, paste

Is there a way to automate this process?
1- create new excel file
2- paste data which is ale+redy in clipboard to this new excel file with python
3- save this excel file

I have tried to find this function in openpyxl and xlsxwriter but there is only function for writing exact data to defined cells.

edit: the data in clipboard is the result from program run before this script

thanks

Comment: can you give example of the data?

Comment: 1. writing to excel file using python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/writing-to-an-excel-spreadsheet
2. pasting from clipboard using python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817290/how-do-i-paste-the-copied-text-from-keyboard-in-python

Comment: the data is combination of numerical data, empty spaces and letters. here is a link to google drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=184rE4FjB8JjHEMSs-E63tek-8GbuL8sb

Answer (score 1):

This method gets data copied from the clipboard and converts it into a DataFrame. You can then select whichever column you want from the DataFrame and use the **to_csv** method to write to the Excel file.

```
pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+', **kwargs)
DataFrame.to_csv()
```

Check out the documentation :

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: The OP wants probably a `XLSX` file, add `.to_excel(...` to your reference list.

Comment: thanks, but I still get the Traceback error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Luka/PycharmProjects/untitled2/novo.py", line 36, in <module>
    pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+', **kwargs)
TypeError: read_clipboard() argument after ** must be a mapping, not module